# Matching up JSON Username & UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm doing the checking for duplicated username method at the moment. Basically, this method will be used during the registration process to check for the Duplicated username. I got all my JSON that filled with usernames from my URL. The main thing is that my method doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
//    DIOSSession *session = [DIOSSession sharedSession];
//    [session user];
//    [[DIOSSession sharedSession] user];
    [self makeRequestJSON];


[self.txtPasswordRegister addTarget:self action:@selector(checkTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
[self.txtPaasswordRegisterReEnter addTarget:self action:@selector(checkTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)makeRequestJSON
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/drupal/rest/user.json"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                     JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id responseObject)
                                     {

                                         _myJson = responseObject;


                                     }
                                     failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id responseObject)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                                     }];

[operation start];

}

- (IBAction)ChkUsername:(id)sender {

    [self makeRequestJSON];
    NSString *match = [_myJson valueForKey:@"name"];

    NSLog(@"match is %@", match);
    if([self.txtUsernameRegister.text isEqualToString: match]){
        [self alertStatus:@"Duplicate Username" :@"Pick another Username" :0];
    }else {
        [self alertStatus:@"You can use this username" :@"Yeahhh" :0];
    }

}
```

Here is my JSON that I got from NSLog.

```
pae1344,
    pae12,
    pae13,
    mai,
    kbank1,
    kbank,
    fuji1,
    fuji,
    admin,
    ""
```

Comment: you need to store all josn response in an Array and then match your current textfield value with that each object of Array... but as my personal experience, its better to pass username to server and server will return that username is exist or not ?

Answer (score 0):

`[self makeRequestJSON];` is a method which calls an asynchronous operation. So, `_myJson` isn't updated immediately, it will take some time.

So, trying to use `_myJson` immediately after calling `makeRequestJSON` won't work.

Because you call it in `viewDidLoad` you may have a value before you try to use it, or you may not. You need to decide how to deal with that.

The JSON you show obviously isn't JSON, but it doesn't appear to be a dictionary, so calling `[_myJson valueForKey:@"name"];` is presumably crashing, and almost certainly not returning a single string. Instead it would seem to be an array of strings and you should be doing something like:

```
if([_myJson containsObject:self.txtUsernameRegister.text]){
    [self alertStatus:@"Duplicate Username" :@"Pick another Username" :0];
} else {
    [self alertStatus:@"You can use this username" :@"Yeahhh" :0];
}
```

*(note that this code looks for an exact match, and you might not want to consider capitalisation / diacritics / ...)*

Ideally, you would get the username from the user, and then call the web service, sending the user choice and getting back a boolean that indicates if it is valid or not. You current solution of returning all usernames is a (bigger) security issue and won't work as the number of users you have goes up...